# How to make each product value change based on its quantity?

Tags: php, html

I have created a select (List/Menu) to change the quantity of the product and added a javascript for it to change on select. The value changes for all the products in the database and quantity column but on the page only the first product value change on the price column and for some reason depending on the number of quantity on the first product it applies to other products.

example to make my point clear: 
Product 1 price = 2
Product 2 price = 3

If I change the quantity on product 1 to '2', on the table I get:
Product 1 price = 4
Product 2 price = 6 even if the quantity to product 2 is set to a different number. The question seems wrongly put but I hope the description made it clear. I have added the whole code because I'm not sure really where is the problem exactly. I hope it's clear to read.

```
<?php require_once('Connections/MJ_conn.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE cart SET quantity=%s WHERE `counter`=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['quantity'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['counter'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_MJ_conn, $MJ_conn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $MJ_conn) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "cart_list.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}

$varuser_CartData = "0";
if (isset($_SESSION["MM_UserID"])) {
  $varuser_CartData = $_SESSION["MM_UserID"];
}
mysql_select_db($database_MJ_conn, $MJ_conn);
$query_CartData = sprintf("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cart.UserID=%s  AND cart.transactioncomplete = 0", GetSQLValueString($varuser_CartData, "int"));
$CartData = mysql_query($query_CartData, $MJ_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_CartData = mysql_fetch_assoc($CartData);
$totalRows_CartData = mysql_num_rows($CartData);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cart List</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IndexStyle.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, intial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <header class="MainHeader">
    <img src="images/header-image-5.jpg">
    <nav><ul>
         <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="Product.php">Products</a></li>
         <li><a href="AboutUs.php">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="ContactUs.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="MainBody">
      <h1>Cart</h1>

      <table width="600" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#CF5C3F">Product</td>
          <td bgcolor="#CF5C3F">Quantity</td>
          <td bgcolor="#CF5C3F">Price</td>
          <td bgcolor="#CF5C3F">Actions</td>
        </tr>
<?php         $totalprice = 0;
$quantity = $row_CartData['quantity'];?>        
<?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo ObtainProductName($row_CartData['ProductID']); ?></td>
    <td><form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
      <div align="center">
        <label for="quantity"></label>
        <select name="quantity" id="quantity" title="<?php echo $quantity ?>" onchange="this.form.submit();">
          <option value="1" selected <?php if (!(strcmp(1, $row_CartData['quantity']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>1</option>
          <option value="2" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, $row_CartData['quantity']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>2</option>
          <option value="3" <?php if (!(strcmp(3, $row_CartData['quantity']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>3</option>
          <option value="4" <?php if (!(strcmp(4, $row_CartData['quantity']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>4</option>
          <option value="5" <?php if (!(strcmp(5, $row_CartData['quantity']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>5</option>
        </select>
        <input name="counter" type="hidden" id="counter" value="<?php echo $row_CartData['counter']; ?>">
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="form1">
    </form></td>
    <td>RM<?php echo ObtainProductPrice($row_CartData['ProductID']) * $quantity ?></td>
    <td><a href="cart_delete.php?recordID=<?php echo $row_CartData['counter']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
    <?php 
    $totalprice = $totalprice + (ObtainProductPrice($row_CartData['ProductID']) * $quantity);?>
  <?php } while ($row_CartData = mysql_fetch_assoc($CartData)); ?>  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>SubTotal</strong>:</div></td>
    <td>RM <?php echo $totalprice ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>Tax:</strong></div></td>
    <td><?php echo ObtainTax(); ?>%</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>Tax amount:</strong></div></td>
    <td>RM<?php 
    $taxRate= ObtainTax();
    $tax=$totalprice*$taxRate/100;
    $totalafter=$totalprice+$tax;
    echo $tax ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div align="right"><strong>Total after Tax:</strong></div></td>
    <td>RM
      <?php 
    $taxRate= ObtainTax();
    $tax=$totalprice*$taxRate/100;
    $totalafter=$totalprice+$tax;
    echo $totalafter
     ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><form name="form2" method="post" action="">
      <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="updatecart" id="updatecart" value="Update Cart">
      </div>
    </form></td>
    <td><form name="form3" method="post" action="">
      <input type="submit" name="checkout" id="checkout" value="Checkout">
    </form></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
      </table>
      <h2><a href="cart_payment_method.php">Choose the payment method</a></h2>
    </div>
    <aside class="SideBar">
<?php include ("/includes/catalogue.php"); ?>
    </aside>
    <Footer class="Footer"> 
        <p><strong>M&amp;J 2017 ©</strong></p>

    </Footer>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($CartData);
?>
```

Comment: why do you create functions inside if statements?

Comment: @julekgwa I'm not sure which part you're referring to.

Comment: you have created two `GetSQLValueString()` inside your `if` statement, and use `mysqli` or `PDO` .`myslq` has been deprecated.

Comment: @julekgwa I was following a tutorial but if I'm not mistaking that code was created with record set. I'm not familiar with mysqli or PDO yet and all my work was through dreamweaver's insert/update/delete records.

Comment: check this post https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp